# Grep - return different line sized contents after a match

Tags: grep, logs, timestamps

I need to find a way for `grep` to return different line sized contents after a match. Some matches have 4 lines after them, other have 20. I need them all.

Every hour I am looking to return the previous hour's log entries, which have timestamps like:

`time: 20200115132443`

To do this, I imagine every hour a cronjob will run the previous hour's timestamp as a grep statement:

`grep "time: 2020011507"`

The problem I'm having is the log has different sizes for certain entries after a match, so just things like `grep -C 5` won't really work all the time.

I'm wondering if I should either be returning all contents of a match up to the next matched grep statement (which would miss the last entry) or if there is some other way to run this. A sample log file snippet looks like:

```
time: 20200115132443
logging stuffs
time: 20200115134543
more logging 
stuffs 
like this
time: 20200115140201 # this should now not be returned
```

Maybe I am overcomplicating and can just run a `grep` statement of the current hour and just grab everything before that hour and after the hour previous.

Comment: This kind of thing is easier to do in awk ex. `awk -v t="20200115134543" '/^time:/{if($2 == t) p=1; else p=0} p' file.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible approach:

```
# variable S0 - date string for hour ago
S0="time: $(date -d '1 hour ago' +%Y%m%d%H)"
# Variable S1 - date string for current hour
S1="time: $(date +%Y%m%d%H)"
# taking lines from between two just defined strings
# including first and excluding second date string
# from file /var/log/log.log
sed -n "/^${S0}/,/^${S1}/ {/^${S1}/"'!p};' /var/log/log.log
```

Now trying to make this a compact one liner:

```
sed -n "/^time: $(date -d '1 hour ago' +%Y%m%d%H)/,/^time: $(date +%Y%m%d%H)/ {/^time: $(date +%Y%m%d%H)/"'!p}' /var/log/log.log
```

You can redirect output to a temp file and work with it.

Or you can simply just add to the end of one liner a pipe and grep:

```
|grep "mystring"
```

.

**P.S.** Depending on OS the command ***date*** format may differ.

- Linux we used here: ***date -d '1 hour ago' +%Y%m%d%H***
- Linux we could use: ***date -d @$(($(date +%s)-3600)) +%Y%m%d%H***
- MacOS X: ***date -r $(($(date +%s)-3600)) +%Y%m%d%H***

etc.

***Updated:*** figured out that the sed part '$d' to delete the last found line does not work, so updated the sed line to work properly.